# Remove all objects from storage meeting a condition - Chrome extension JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension, promise

I want to write a function that returns a Promise that resolves after removing all objects from storage that have a property with a certain value, but to do that I need to call remove in a loop, which is asynchronous, so I don't know how I could safely resolve after removing everything.

Here is how I can resolve after removing one object:

```
function remove(value) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Get all objects from storage
    chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(allStorage) {
      // Loop through keys
      for(let key in allStorage) {
        // Remove if the property === value
        if(allStorage[key].property === value) {
          chrome.storage.local.remove(key, function() {
            // Done removing one object
            resolve();
          });
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

But I want to remove all of them:

```
function removeAll(value) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Get all objects from storage
    chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(allStorage) {
      // Loop through keys
      for(let key in allStorage) {
        // Remove if the property === value
        if(allStorage[key].property === value) {
          chrome.storage.local.remove(key, function() {
            // Done removing one object
          });
        }
      }
      // How can I safely resolve here, when all objects are removed?
      resolve();
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Extension APIs are now promisified https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/promises/ That would allow you to use async/await or Promise.all()

Answer (score 0):

After learning more about promises I ended up doing this. I feel like there must be a way to make it cleaner though.

```
function removeAll(value) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    let promises = [];
    // Get all objects from storage
    chrome.storage.local.get(null, allStorage => {
      // Loop through keys
      for(let key in allStorage) {
        // Remove if the property === value
        if(allStorage[key].property === value) {
          // Create a new promise that resolves when object is removed
          let promise = new Promise(resolve => {
            chrome.storage.local.remove(key, _ => {
              console.log('deleted object from storage');
              resolve();
            });
          });
          // Push to array of promises
          promises.push(promise);
        }
      }
      // Resolve the function return promise when all promises in array resolve
      Promise.all(promises).then(_ => {
        resolve();
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Oh apparently remove accepts an array.

```
function removeAll(value) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    // Get all storage
    chrome.storage.local.get(null, allStorage => {
      let keysToRemove = [];
      // Loop through all keys
      for(let key in allStorage) {
        // Get the object associated with key
        let object = allStorage[key];
        // Push to remove array if value matches argument
        if(object.property === value) {
          keysToRemove.push(key);
        }
      }
      chrome.storage.local.remove(keysToRemove, _ => {
        resolve();
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: `remove` accepts an array so indeed you can significantly simplify and speed up the code.